# centrar un tabla con bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Quiero centrar mi tabla pero no sé cómo hacerlo. Ya probé varias opciones, dejo imagen y código.
¿Alguna idea?

```
<body class="container">
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <br />
    <br />

    <h3 align="center">FILTRAR TRANSACCIONES CON SALDO SIN MOVIMIENTOS</h3>

    <br />
    <br />


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">

        <table class="table table-hover table-dark">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <asp:GridView ID="grDatos" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlign="Center" onrowcommand="grDatos_RowCommand">
                <Columns>
                  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Transacciones" DataField="TransaccionId" />
                  <asp:BoundField HeaderText=" Codigo de cuenta" DataField="CodigoCuenta" />
                  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Descripcion de cuenta " DataField="CuentaDescripcion" />
                  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cantidad de movimiento" DataField="cantidadMovimiento" />
                  <asp:ButtonField CommandName="detalles" Text="Detalles" />
                </Columns>
                <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblNoTieneDato" runat="server" Text="LA CONSULTA NO TRAE DATOS" ForeColor="Yellow" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
              </asp:GridView>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo mejor siempre es crear un contenedor bootstrap despues del body para que todo quede centrado, busca mas información en google sobre los contenedores

Comment: lo hice pero nada! igual sigo probando..

Comment: <div class="container">         todo el contenido         <div> esto con bootstrap deberia funcionar

Comment: estoy jugando con los cols! pero bueno a seguir probando... GRACIAS A TODOS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba con la clase **d-flex justify-content-center** en el div del row
Así:

```html
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
```

Comment: Genio!!!! Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar la clase container en el div

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://201.116.226.217:50/coti/cotizador/img/w1.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
  #mi_tabla{
     overflow:auto;
     height:500px;
     width:auto;
     padding:0px;
  }
table  { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }+
thead { margin-top:-10px}
.tableFixHead    { overflow-y: auto; height: 100px; }
.tableFixHead th { position: sticky; top: 0; }
</style>
<body>
<div class="container" id="mi_tabla">
  <table class="table table-hover table-dark tableFixHead" >
    <thead>
      <tr class="">
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Mensaje</th>
        <th scope="col">Cliente</th>
        <th scope="col">Fecha y Hora</th>
        <th scope="col">Observaciones</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td scope="row"><strong>1</strong></td>
        <td>Buen día</td>
        <td>Juan Pérez</td>
        <td>2019-04-25 13:00:00</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td scope="row"><strong>1</strong></td>
        <td>Buen día</td>
        <td>Juan Pérez</td>
        <td>2019-04-25 13:00:00</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td scope="row"><strong>1</strong></td>
        <td>Buen día</td>
        <td>Juan Pérez</td>
        <td>2019-04-25 13:00:00</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td scope="row"><strong>1</strong></td>
        <td>Buen día</td>
        <td>Juan Pérez</td>
        <td>2019-04-25 13:00:00</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

    <!--Script de boostrap--> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no sigue igual!

Comment: Intenta creando solo el html, y cambia las versiones de boostrap que estas usando

Comment: Una vez que te funcione trabaja sobre ese y lo remplazas

Comment: Excelente aporte @RamiroRM gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Al que debes de darle centrar es al div contenedor

```html
<h3 align="center">FILTRAR TRANSACCIONES CON SALDO SIN MOVIMIENTOS</h3>

    <br />
    <br />


    <div class="row">            
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">

<table class="table table-hover table-dark">          
    <tr>            
        <td>
            <asp:GridView ID="grDatos" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlign="Center" onrowcommand="grDatos_RowCommand">
                <Columns>
                  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Transacciones" DataField="TransaccionId" />
                  <asp:BoundField HeaderText =" Codigo de cuenta" DataField="CodigoCuenta"  />
                  <asp:BoundField HeaderText ="Descripcion de cuenta " DataField="CuentaDescripcion" />
                  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cantidad de movimiento" DataField="cantidadMovimiento" />
                  <asp:ButtonField CommandName ="detalles" Text ="Detalles" />
                </Columns>
             <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
             <EmptyDataTemplate >
            <asp:Label ID="lblNoTieneDato" runat="server"  
                Text="LA CONSULTA NO TRAE DATOS" ForeColor="Yellow" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>                    
                <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: no che solo me alineo el texto dentro de las tablas

Answer (score 0):

Después de tus divs `container` y `row` crea un `div class="table-responsive"` ahí dentro tu tabla funcionó para mi. Usando Bootstrap obviamente.

Comment: Bienvenido Akilae. Por favor, ve a [answer] para mejorar tu respuesta... Tal como está puede ser sujeto a puntuaciones negativas o reportes...

Comment: Deberías explicar por qué tu propuesta soluciona el problema.